# How to Extract columns (almost the same) between two strings , using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a very large text file, which contains 1339018 lines, I wanted to extract three parts:

my FILE.txt

```
.
.
.
-----------------------
first ATOMIC CHARGES
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
My charges :   -0.0000000

------------------------
.
..
.
-----------------------
first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.208137    0.054313
   1 C :   -0.206691    0.053890
   2 C :   -0.266791    0.395830
   3 C :   -0.262729    0.395691
   4 S :   -0.184730    0.179002
   5 H :    0.023341   -0.009535
   6 H :    0.023405   -0.009489
   7 H :    0.042728   -0.029862
   8 H :    0.039605   -0.029841
My charges :   -1.0000000

------------------------
.
.
.
.
-----------------------
first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.086045    0.075562
   1 C :   -0.085256    0.075871
   2 C :    0.022683    0.483590
   3 C :    0.025286    0.483583
   4 S :    0.246328   -0.079498
   5 H :    0.215005   -0.003936
   6 H :    0.215043   -0.003948
   7 H :    0.224379   -0.015598
   8 H :    0.222578   -0.015627
My charges :    1.0000000

------------------------
.
.
.
```

I tried with script below, in order to extract and convert the fourth column to a list (for example:

oX = [-0.157853, -0.156875, -0.143714 ...]

oY = [- 0.208137, -0.206691, ...]

oZ = [-0.086045, -0.085256, ...]

but unfortunately, the third loop does not work.

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0]
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN')[1].split("My charges :   -1.0000000")[0]
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN')[1].split("My charges :    1.0000000")[0]
```

**is it possible??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the required values using a regular expression:

```
import re

data = []
block = []

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        values = re.findall('\s+\d+.*?(-?\d+\.\d+)', row)

        if len(values):
            block.append(float(values[0]))
        elif row.startswith('first ATOMIC') and len(block):
            data.append(block)
            block = []

if len(block):
    data.append(block)            

oX, oY, oZ = data    

print oX
print oY
print oZ
```

This would print:

```
[-0.157853, -0.156875, -0.143714, -0.140489, 0.058926, 0.128758, 0.128814, 0.14242, 0.140013]
[-0.208137, -0.206691, -0.266791, -0.262729, -0.18473, 0.023341, 0.023405, 0.042728, 0.039605]
[-0.086045, -0.085256, 0.022683, 0.025286, 0.246328, 0.215005, 0.215043, 0.224379, 0.222578]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making the one subtle change in the last line as shown below. You were very close!

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0]
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN')[1].split("My charges :   -1.0000000")[0]
     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES AND SPIN')[2].split("My charges :    1.0000000")[0]
     #                                                          ^ change this
```

Comment: Great. If my answer solved your problem, please select it as the correct answer. And happy coding!

Comment: I'm having a hard time every time to validate the correct answer, because each time, I find more than one answer.
can I validate more than one answer ??

in any case,  thank you.